# Vue gives me a warning about uncommited changes

Tags: vue-cli-4

so I just created a new vue project with vuecli. I played around a bit and then wanted to add a new plugin using `vue add <plugin>`. Now I get the following warning:

> There are uncommited changes in the current repository, it's
>   recommended to commit or stash them first.

What's that about? Why does this error message use this specific terminology? I'm not using any versioning system, since I'm just playing around and even if I would - that warning would still confuse me. Does vue-cli use some kind of internal versioning system?

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is 6months+ old, but I ran into the same issue.

I am using `vue-cli` inside MS Studio Code.  It appears that Code has a "Source Control" support which (for me) is using `git`.  I didn't configure this directly - I assume that Code found `git` when it installed and enabled it for me.

I believe that `vue-cli` detects any uncommitted changes (based on [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3250)) in the underlying source code control mechanism.

For me - using MS Studio Code > Source Control (as per picture attached) allowed changes to be staged and `vue-cli` install to proceed without the warning.

[image]

Edit:

It appears (for me) that `vue` is adding the `git` integration on project creation - below is default from `vue ui`.  Which I believe is where `vue-cli` is detecting unstaged changes.

[image]